# How to Validate large xml streams, in a way that it creates chunk of stream read and send to other threads for processing while validation continues

Tags: c#, xml, wcf, sockets, tcp

I am looking for efficiant way to validate large XML files on following senarios:

1) Files are receiving from network.

2) Validation of xml is required based on DTD provided.

3) There are other threads running which will process data in a particular node of a file that node information is configurable.

4) validation must not block other threads to wait for whole file to validate.

As this is long running processes, xml files will be received on port continuously for hours or days or months with unknown break in between.

I need a solutions that

1) don't let the reader/validator read until end of the file and then send the result of validation.

2) As Data node contains all the data, stop the validator to data node begin , start reading fixed amount of data only and send read data to standing threads to process asynchronously and let the validator continue reading and sending.

Is the above approach correct ? Is there any such xml validator exists? if not how to create it? I tried inheriting IXmlLineInfo, IXmlNamespaceResolver in a class but that seems a big work to implement them.

Comment: What happens if the final close node of your XML document is missing? You might not be able to fully validate the document until you hit end of file, so what behaviour would you want to see in that situation?

Comment: I'll schedule rollback for that transaction

Answer (score 1):

[XmlReader](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlreader.aspx) can parse the file and validate inline with [XmlReaderSettings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlreadersettings.aspx).

```
XmlReaderSettings settings = new XmlReaderSettings();
settings.ValidationType = ValidationType.Schema;
settings.Schemas.Add(null, path);
settings.ValidationFlags |= XmlSchemaValidationFlags.ProcessInlineSchema;
settings.ValidationFlags |= XmlSchemaValidationFlags.ProcessSchemaLocation;
settings.ValidationFlags |= XmlSchemaValidationFlags.ReportValidationWarnings;
settings.ValidationEventHandler += new System.Xml.Schema.ValidationEventHandler(ValidationEventHandler);
```

Comment: @ImranRizvi It is a forward-only reader. As it reads, it checks if the document respects the schema. If it finds otherwise, it will raise an event (the `ValidationEventHandler` from the code snippet). If you are looking for something more sophisticated, I am afraid that you will have to implement it yourself. Your use-case seems to be quite unique (sending one document for months?!).

Answer (score 0):

I think it might be possible to solve this using the validation and streaming capabilities in Saxon-EE (which of course can be called from C#), but it's a tough requirement and producing a design is beyond the scope of a typical StackOverflow answer: it's something that would justify investing in a few days' consultancy.

I'm actually thinking here of XSD validation rather than DTD validation. It's easy enough to generate an XSD from your DTD.

It might be that the solution is as simple as this:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="3.0" ...>
<xsl:mode streamable="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="record">
  <xsl:try>
    <xsl:result-document href="{@id}.xml" validation="strict">
      <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
    </xsl:result-document>
    <xsl:catch/>
  </xsl:try>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

The only part of your requirement that this doesn't obviously meet is that it all runs in a single thread. We have multi-threading capabilities in Saxon but they don't mix well with streaming; however with a more detailed understanding of the requirements there should be a solution to that.